# Generate a number in the subject line for a contact form

Tags: php, contact-form

I have a contact form which consists of following fields:

- First name
- Last name
- Phone
- Email
- and Comment

Whenever the user submitting this form to my email so the subject value should take an auto
Number automatically generated by PHP.

Here is what I have so far

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "wouldn't want some spam mail would ya?";      
    $email_subject = "New Property From Customer";

    function died($error) {   
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if (!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if (!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if (!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if (strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?> 

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Your Property has been Posted please check your email address.

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: for auto generated number there is a function in php `rand()` see link http://in3.php.net/rand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't specify where you want to get this number from.
Since you said generate I'll assume you're creating it on the spot. So maybe add onto the end of `$email_subject` something like `$rand(100,1000)`?

Maybe you should clarify what you're asking for?

Side note:
Consider using `filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to check emails, not some preg_match. More info on that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php).

Comment: thanks dear alex l but it is not in sequence eg one is 101,232,565   can i get from 101 to 102 and so on.

Comment: So perhaps you'll have to store on your server a file/database that can give you the next sequential number. You could store the last number in a .txt file and increment it every time you send an email. Or you could store each email in a database and on the insertion of a new row you can get the last inserted Id, which would then be your subject's number! Does that help at all?

Comment: DEAR Alex L how can i create text file and store all these number

Comment: thanks dear Alex L that is used to write to the file but i need to retrieve and use as a value of my subject and sent to my email.

Comment: Yes if you click on a couple links you'll find what you're looking for. Unfortunately im not here to code it for you, I'm sure a little research will get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

to generate random number simply user rand() function as below

```
echo rand($fromRange,$toRange);
```

and you will get random number between the range you specified